# Developer Story UI issue - Compensation preferences

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story

The drop down for currency selection when choosing your desired compensation is not aligned correctly.

[image]

Browser: Chrome Version 50.0.2661.75 m
OS: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed, it'll be live after our next production build.